# In .NET Core Data Protection, how do you get ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault() to encrypt the existing keys?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-keyvault

We have an App Service app which requires a centralised key which we want to store in a blob and protect with encryption.

How do you get ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault() to encrypt the existing keys?

I have the following code in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("myAppName")
    .PersistKeysToAzureBlobStorage(new Uri("https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/secrets/keys.xml?<SAS>"))
    .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault(new Uri("https://myvault.vault.azure.net/keys/dp-key/"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

..but if I look at the XML key file in the blob storage area, it has the keys in plain text together with a warning that they are not encrypted.   Why is the .ProtectKeysWithAzureKeyVault() call seemingly have no effect?  It works if I persist the keys to the local file system, but not if I use Blob storage.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the keys are immutable, meaning that they don't change once they are created?  The alternative is to create your own provider and encrypt the entire key-ring (not the individual keys).

I blogged earlier about how to write your own key-ring store and store it in Azure Key Vault.

- [Storing the ASP.NET Core Data Protection Key Ring in Azure Key Vault](https://www.edument.se/en/blog/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault)